# Is this true for $n \geq 1:\sigma(4^n) \bmod 4=3$ and how do i show it if it is?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisor-sum

Some computations [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Table+of+%5B+sigma(4%5En)+mod+4+%5D,+n%3D1+to+5000) in wolfram alpha which i did show that :$$\sigma(4^n) \bmod 4=3$$ is true at a least from $n=1$ to $5000$ , really i don't know how do i can factorise $4^n$ over $\sigma $ sum of power divisor function .

**My question here is:**
Is this true for $n \geq 1:\sigma(4^n) \bmod 4=3$ and how do i show it if it is?

**Note:** I checked that  for some  studies about periodicity of divisibilty among power of sum divisor function .

Comment: Almost all divisors of $4^n$ are divisible by $4$ and contribute nothing to $\sigma(4^n)$ mod $4$.  Which divisors are remaining?

Answer (score 2):

The divisors of $4^n=2^{2n}$ are $2^k$ for $k=0,1,\dots,2n$, hence if $n\geq 1$ then
$$ \sigma(4^n)=\sum_{k=0}^{2n}2^k=2^{2n+1}-1\equiv 3\mod 4$$
since $4$ divides $2^{2n+1}$ when $n\geq 1$.